# Bottom Space Tab Bar iOS issue

Tags: ios

I have added a tab bar controller. There is a thin white space left at the bottom below the tab bar in iOS7 and a black space in iOS6. Any idea what might be the problem?[image]

Comment: Can you post some code? It's hard to know the answer with just an image of the problem. I can also see theres a thin black line at almost the top of the tab bar. Perhaps you initialized the tab bar with wrong 'y' origin? It seems to be raised up.

Answer (score 0):

**Probably your icon size is not matching to the standard design pattern: ***

According to the [apple link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html) icon image size should be ***30x30 for Normal / 60x60. for Retina @2x ***

and Here if you are using the static title into Image than it's not a great idea to embed the title of the tab into the image—you're going to have poor accessibility and localization results like that.